# How to animate dynamically generated html in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm fetching tabular data from the server using jquery's ajax function. And I'm using the .html function to assign the fetched data inside a div with an id of list_forms. 
How do I animate it?
I'm trying `$('#list_forms').html(data).show('slow');` but its not working.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "item_lister.php",
    data: "category=" +  action,
    success: function(data){
        $('#list_forms').html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: What does `its not working mean`? What doesn't work? Is the `#list_forms` already displayed? what do you try to animate `#list_forms` or something in it? questions questions :)

Comment: The result shows up but I want to animate it as it shows up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "item_lister.php",
   data: "category=" +  action,
   success: function(data){
       $('#list_forms')
         .hide()
         .html(data)
         .fadeIn();
   }
```

});